# Generate and record Midi sounds Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, midi

I am creating a piano game for Android and I want to play MIDI sounds and record them. I was considering using javax.sound for this, but it is not compatible with Android.

An important point is that at this stage, I do not want to connect an external MIDI keyboard and only use the keys on the screen.

Perhaps using the MIDI format to solve this problem is not the best approach. I would like to ask for your advice on how I can achieve this. May be there are some good ways to do it.

One possible solution to the issue could be to concatenate WAV files with recorded notes. However, this seems like a bit of a hacky workaround.